# Copyable scrolling text in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scroll, tkinter-canvas

I wanted to create a scrollable, copyable text in tkinter. This text should be immutable *to the user*, but I can change it.

Although this seems simple, there are some ways to approach it, but there are unsatisfactory things about each approach.*

1. Use a `state=disabled` `Text` widget.

However, this also disallows *my program* to change it, which means I have to temporarily enable the widget, which can result it the user adding a character or two if they spam a key in the textbox.(Yes, it does matter, I want it to be *absolutely immutable*.)

2. Use create_text on a `Canvas`, which is scollable.

However, AFAIK, I cannot copy such text.

3. `pack` Labels into a `Canvas`, which is scrollable.

However, AFAIK, They don't scroll with the canvas.

One thing that could possible work is `Canvas.create_window`, but I can't even find a document of it, and the `help` text says nothing useful.

```
help> tkinter.Canvas.create_window
Help on function create_window in tkinter.Canvas:

tkinter.Canvas.create_window = create_window(self, *args, **kw)
    Create window with coordinates x1,y1,x2,y2.

help>
```

[sic]

Comment: What about returning `"break"` from events like `KeyPress`?

Comment: wait, you can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this approach?:

```py
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import tkinter as tk

def return_break(event:tk.Event) -> str:
    return "break"


root = tk.Tk()
text = ScrolledText(root)
text.pack()
text.bind("<KeyPress>", return_break)
text.insert("end", "Hello"+"\n"*40+"World.")

root.mainloop()
```

You return `"break"` from the events that you don't want `tkinter` to handle like `"<KeyPress>"`. For this approach to work, when inserting new text, don't use `.insert("insert", ...)` as the user can change that, user `.insert("end", ...)` instead.

Comment: whoops, didn't think you could do that. I always thought you can only add a custom handler but not block the default processing. Thanks!

Comment: also, i think replacing `return_break` with `(lambda x:'break')` would be more clear, but both works.

Comment: Note that on some X11-based systems (eg: linux), some window managers have default bindings that let you paste with the mouse. If you leave the widget enabled it may be possible for the user to insert data using only the mouse.

Comment: @BryanOakley True but this approach can be expanded to those events as well, like `"<Mouse-3>"`. But your answer is more correct given that OP doesn't insert in the textbox from other threads - which isn't advisable.

Answer (score 3):

> ...I have to temporarily enable the widget, which can result it the user adding a character or two if they spam a key in the textbox.(Yes, it does matter, I want it to be absolutely immutable.)

I disagree with this statement. It would be impossible for a user to change the text widget when you enable the widget, insert or delete text, and then disable the widget within a small block of code. Within that block, no events are processed so the user cannot possibly enter data in that period of time. By the time you let tkinter start processing events again, the widget will have been reset to the disabled state.

The correct solution is to set the state to disabled, and temporarily enable it when your program needs to insert data.

Comment: but tkinter callbacks are THREADED. I don't want to fall into the pit of race conditions.

Comment: @00001H: _"but tkinter callbacks are THREADED."_ - no, they are not. Tkinter is single threaded. Events go on a queue that is processed by the main thread.

Answer (score -3):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

# Create the root window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create a ScrolledText widget with the specified text
text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, wrap='word')
text.insert('1.0', """This is some immutable text that can be scrolled and copied
...
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
..
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
This is some immutable text that can be scrolled and copied""")

# Configure the widget to be non-editable
text.config(state='disabled')

# Pack the widget and start the event loop
text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you not read the question? See point 1 then.